# How do I fix the Missing CategoryName Error Message?

Tags: vb.net

No matter what I change it always shows 'Failed to initialize because CategoryName is missing.' I am trying to use a button on one form to open up another, but this keeps happening.

```
Private Sub BtnSCO_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSCO.Click
    Dim oForm As New BoogalooForm 'Boogaloo is the second form
    oForm.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the "it" of "it always shows"? What code? What line of code?

Comment: What is in the BoogalooForm's Form.Load?

Comment: Nothing is in the form.load

Comment: If you set [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) then Visual Studio will give you some guidance as to where the problem is.